# merging irregular time series datset with a regular time series data in R

Tags: r, merge

Hi I am trying to merge two datasets, one with regular time series (dataframe A) and one with irregular time series (dataframe B). The two dataframes look something like:

Dataframe A:

| time | country | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 198001 | A | 1 |
| 198002 | A | 0 |
| 198003 | A | 0 |
| 198004 | A | -1 |
| ... |  |  |
| 201210 | Z | 1 |
| 201211 | Z | 0 |
| 201212 | Z | 0 |

Dataframe B:

| time | country | party | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 198002 | A | A1 | X |
| 201210 | Z | Z1 | Y |
| 201212 | Z | Z2 | Z |

Ive tried using full_join from dplyr but then it yielded NAs for all timeframes that did not overlap with the observations in dataframe 2.

What I have now looks like:

| time | country | Action | Party | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 198001 | A | 1 | NA | NA |
| 198002 | A | 0 | A1 | X |
| 198003 | A | 0 | A1 | NA |
| 198004 | A | -1 | A1 | NA |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 201210 | Z | 1 | Z1 | Y |
| 201211 | Z | 0 | Z1 | NA |
| 201212 | Z | 0 | Z2 | Z |

Instead, I would want the observations in the non-overlapping timeframe (NAs) to be replaced with the last observation in dataframe 2.

So the merged dataframe would look like:

| time | country | Action | Party | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 198001 | A | 1 | NA | NA |
| 198002 | A | 0 | A1 | X |
| 198003 | A | 0 | A1 | X |
| 198004 | A | -1 | A1 | X |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 201210 | Z | 1 | Z1 | Y |
| 201211 | Z | 0 | Z1 | Y |
| 201212 | Z | 0 | Z2 | Z |

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `full_join` and then `fill` `party` and `variable` columns.

```
result <- dplyr::full_join(A, B, by = c("time", "country")) %>%
           tidyr::fill(party, variable, .direction = 'down')

result
```